# How may I find the version of an installed stack?

Tags: ros, orocos, stack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when a stack is not in the .rosinstall file, do I have a mean to know what's the package version.

To be concrete I don't know if which version of orocos_toolcahin_ros is installed
http://www.ros.org/wiki/orocos_toolchain_ros

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9164/how-may-i-find-the-version-of-an-installed-stack-?/) by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 352 on 2011-02-22

Post score: 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using Diamondback:

> rosversion orocos_toolchain_ros

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on 2011-02-22**:
This is great !

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The CMakeLists.txt of the stack, i.e. that file that lies right next to stack.xml contains the stack version. You can either browse the stack's repo online or check it out and check that file. Also, if you are installing from debian packages, an 'apt-cache show deb-package' shows you the stack version somewhere on top of the output.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Willy Lambert](https://answers.ros.org/users/168/willy-lambert/) on 2011-02-22**:
Thanks for this, it is not the best way to have the version but it will be usefull when I'll code my own stack !